# ASP.NET MVC 2 C#: Short hand IF within loop?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, if-statement

I'm trying to find out how I can put a condition within my loop as I print out list items...

```
<ul>
   <% foreach (var filter in Model.Filter)
     { %>

     <li <% filter.TagChecked == 1 ? //yes : //no %>><%: filter.TagLabel %> <span class="closeImage"><img src="/Content/Images/filterButtonClose.gif" /></span></li>

   <% } %>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to see if a filter is checked... if yes, then I need to write the class and also add the image. If not, then just write a normal li

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just return the needed string:

```
<%: filter.TagChecked == 1 ? " class=\"myclass\"" : string.Empty %>
```

Comment: Any reason why you chose to use string.Empty as opposed to ""?

Comment: @dcolumbus - I just like the explicitness of it. It evaluates to the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

```
<ul>
<% foreach (var filter in Model.Filter)
 { %>

 <li <%: filter.TagChecked == 1 ? "class=\"some-class\"" : "" %>><%: filter.TagLabel %> <span class="closeImage"><img src="/Content/Images/filterButtonClose.gif" /></span></li>

<% } %>
</ul>
```

Comment: With .NET 4.0, it is better practice to use `<%:%>` instead of `<%=%>`, as it adds HTML encoding.